# Import self-signed certificate with private key on Windows from command prompt

Tags: command-line, certificate, windows-server-2012, ssl-certificate, certutil

Using inetmgr, I made a pfx file containing the public and private keys for a certificate. Now I'm trying to install the pfx into another machine from the command prompt with

```
certutil -p <password> -importpfx root <path_to_pfxfile>
```

Unfortunately, this is only importing the public key. If I use the certmgr snap-in I can import both keys, but I need to be able to automate this. Can anybody help?

Comment: The `Import-PfxCertificate` PowerShell command will probably do what you want. I'm not in a position to test this right now, but the documentation is here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848625(v=wps.630).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it on Monday. Post it as an answer, and if it works i'll pick it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Import-PfxCertificate` PowerShell command will probably do what you want. .

This would import the certificate(s) and keys stored in `my.pfx` file into the `Trusted Root Certificate Authorities` certificate store for the local machine.

```
Import-PfxCertificate –FilePath C:\mypfx.pfx cert:\localMachine\Root -Password $password
```

---

You may need to experiment a bit to find the name used for the certificate store of interest. I did this by copying the thumbprint of a certificate in the relevent store from the UI, removing spaces and then running

`ls|where {$_.Thumbprint -eq "<thumprint value here, with spaces removed>"}`

Which gave me this as part of the output.

`Directory: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\Root`

Comment: This answer was a life saver for me.  Tip about finding available cert stores: From Powershell: `PS> ls cert:\ ` will show list of top level dirs, e.g., `CurrentUser` and `LocalMachine`.  Any user can write to `cert:\CurrentUser` but `cert:\LocalMachine` requires special permissions.  Include arg `-Exportable` if you need to access private key later.  For password, try: `-Password (ConvertTo-SecureString "your-password-here" -AsPlainText -Force)`

Answer (score 0):

certutil does not import the private key. You'll have to use another tool such as pk12util.

This question has been already answered. Please attempt to find a solution to your problem before asking a question.

See this answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/647658/how-to-add-an-existing-key-to-the-certutil-key-database

And this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161403/how-to-setup-dart-to-use-a-ca-ssl-certificate/27176982#27176982

Comment: I should have been more specific. The other machine is really a windows azure web role, and I need the certificate imported when the role starts up. So using open-ssl tools are not an option.